# How do I render trains as trees in Dyalog APL using dyalogscript?

Tags: apl, dyalog

```
$ cat a.apl 
]Box on -trains=tree
⎕←≢,⊢
$ dyalogscript a.apl

VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: ⎕SE.UCMD
```

While in RIDE the same script produces:

```
 ≢,⊢
┌─┼─┐
≢ , ⊢
```

How can I get the same train rendering in dyalogscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `]Box` is a user command, you need to [enable user commands](https://aplcart.info?q=enable%20user%20commands):

```
(⎕NS⍬).(_←enableSALT⊣⎕CY'salt')
```

---

It is likely that a future version will have a neater way to do this, namely by adding a parameter to the `#!` line of the script.

Comment: Thanks @Adam!
Just a note that it seems user commands can't be expressed like this:
```
    (⎕NS ⍬).(_←enableSALT⊣⎕CY'salt') ⋄ ]Box on -trains=tree ⋄ ⎕←(≡,⊢)
```
That is, they need to be on their own line.

Comment: @justin2004 Yes, because they are not using APL syntax. However, there's a proper syntax equivalent: `⎕SE.UCMD'box on -trains=tree'`